# ASUS N56VZ-S4209P Screen saver, Screen dimming,sleep/hibernation mode not working according to power management settings

Tags: windows-8, display, power-management, screensaver, asus-laptop

I have a problem with my ASUS N56VZ-S4209P(Win8, I7-3630QM) laptop. If I use the fn+f7 command to turn off the screen it turns on by itself after a few seconds (the time varies between 1-10 seconds). In addition to this my screensaver doesn't activate at all and the laptop doesn't dim its screen after X minutes or goes into sleep/hibernation mode as specified in the power options when plugged in or on battery. As far as my knowledge goes it's not caused by the mouse or track pad at all since I can unplug my mouse and disable the track pad but the problem persist.  I presume this is caused by the same problem?

Does anyone know of a fix for this problem? It would be greatly appreciated.

.
.
.
I seem to have found a solution to the problem related to the screen that turns itself on again. The Power4Gear application has a setting which enables you to turn a "Presentation mode" "On" and "Off", if that setting is "Off" then it doesn't turn the screen on without any human interaction. Thus that part of the problem is fixed.

Comment: Maybe came with some crappy Asus power management software installed that overrides the settings.

Comment: @André - I seem to have found a solution to the problem related to the screen that turns itself on again. The Power4Gear application has a setting which enables you to turn a "Presentation mode" "On" and "Off", if that setting is off then it doesn't turn the screen on without any human interaction. Thus that part of the problem is fixed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is Power4Gear?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, you'll be able to mark it as the correct answer in 24 hours.

Comment: @André it's a power management utility from ASUS.

Comment: That's what I thought ;-) Glad you were abel to solve it.

Comment: I can't answer my own question right now since I'm a new user with less than 10 reputation points and the question was posted less than 8 hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "powercfg /energy" from an admin command prompt to gen an analysis report, it usually indicates what causes the sleep problem.

Comment: If I try to run that I get the following error report "The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded."

Comment: That is a bit strange, it should be in c:\windows\system32. Have you checked the event viewer for any errors logged in connection to running the powercfg command or at the time you try to make the machine go to sleep?

Comment: I don't see any log related to powercfg or sleep. Just to be clear, I don't have problems putting the computer to sleep myself, it's just letting it put itself to sleep or dim the brightness to save power that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that behavior is also related to power savings settings and energy schemes defined. I would say you have some problem with your Windows installation if you cannot run the powercfg /energy command. Hard to tell whats wrong.

Comment: Ok, what I did now. I restarted my laptop, ran the powercfg/energy command again, this time it ran without any errors. The first run on battery power it gave results of 8 (E)rrors, 8 (W)arnings 20 (I)nformational. The second run I plugged the power chord in (thus charging) then it gave 5E, 6W, 21I. Then I ran it again but this time disconnecting my mouse and cooling pad but still charging, then it gave 6E, 5W, 24I. I saved all the reports on a diff location after creation so i can review them.

Comment: But here comes the good news, just after the second run, the screen saver started. And after each of the following runs the screen saver started by itself no problem. I tested if the screen dimming works and yes it does now. And the screen switches off after by itself as it should. Thus it seems as if the problem fixed itself after the first run was completed. I haven't checked to see if it goes into sleep mode but i will do that now.

Comment: Ok did all the checks to see if it works and everything (Screen dimming, Screen turning off and laptop entering sleep mode) seems to be working as it should.  I also checked to see if those "normal" functions work if the "Presentation mode" is enabled and it doesn't, so that Presentation mode overrides all the normal power options and keeps the screen brightness constant as well as keeps the screen saver from starting and the computer from entering sleep mode. Thus thanks for the quick help on fixing these minor issues.

Comment: I had an extremely similar issue just pop up one day. The moment I started the `powercfg /energy` command, it just went away. I did not need to analyze anything, this report generator fixed everything.